# Can I copy a file from the Web to a local machine at the command line?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

Is it possible to copy a file at a HTTP:// URL to a local directory in a BAT or CMD file?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget).

Comment: Cross-platform as well.

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 2):

Or [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) will work too. It is supposedly Windows too but I have never tried it on Windows.

Comment: Curl works in the windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

Side note: [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) works fine from PowerShell as well.